# VueJS: Is It Possible to Automatically Include One Component in Another Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to automatically include the contents of one component in a named slot of another component.  I.e., something like this:

```
Vue.component('comp-one', {
  template: `
    <div class="comps>
      <div class="comp-two">
        <slot name="compTwo"></slot>
      </div>

      <div class="comp-one">
         <slot></slot>
      </div>   
    </div>
   `
})

Vue.component('comp-two', {

  slot: 'compTwo',  
  template: `
     <div class="sub-comp-two">
      <!-- content goes here -->
     <slot></slot>
     </div>
`

})
```

The idea is that if someone uses `<comp-two>Some content</comp-two>`, it will automatically get added to the slot compTwo in comp-one.  Is there a way to do this?

NOTE:  I made up `slot: 'compTwo'`.  Just trying to illustrate what I'd like to accomplish.

Comment: Why not simply put the component in the template instead of the slot? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I could cut down on the amount of code needed to be written.  For instance:  `<comp-two>Content</comp-two>` as opposed to `<comp-two slot="compTwo">Content</comp-two>`.  That's my main goal, to reduce as much as possible the amount of code needed to get the desired end result. [NOTE:  I"m referring to the amount of code needed by one using the component]

Comment: That still doesn't make much sense - if you put the component in the other one right away you won't need to write it again at all. What are you _actually_ trying to do?